# Error updating One to One relation Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I update entity Framework row entry which has one to one relationship to another table. I get this error on `_context.SaveChanges();`. I have a class called `NewsletterComponents` with one-to-one relation with `NewsletterNewPlants`. Not sure why the row fails to update throwing duplicate errors. Should I delete it first then reinsert it?

**Error Message**

> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
> 'dbo.NewsletterNewPlants' with unique index
> 'IX_NewsletterNewPlants_NewPlantComponentId'. The duplicate key value
> is (169).

**OnPostUPdate Method**

```
public IActionResult OnPostUpdateComponent(NewsletterComponents component, int? newsId, int? shortArticleId)
        {
            var dbComponent = _context.NewsletterComponents.Find(component.NewsletterComponentId);
            if (dbComponent == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            dbComponent.NewsletterNewPlants = component.newsletterNewPlants;
            dbComponent.NewsletterComponentSubline = component.NewsletterComponentSubline;
            dbComponent.NewsletterComponentHeadline = component.NewsletterComponentHeadline;
            _context.Update(dbComponent);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToPage(new { id = dbComponent.NewsletterComponentId});
        }
```

**Parent NewsletterComponents Model**

```
public partial class NewsletterComponents
    {
        public int NewsletterComponentId { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string NewsletterComponentHeadline { get; set; }
        public string NewsletterComponentSubline { get; set; }
        public virtual NewsletterNewPlants NewsletterNewPlants { get; set; }


    }
```

**Child NewsletterNewPlants Model**

```
public class NewsletterNewPlants
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("NewsletterComponents")]
        public int NewPlantComponentId { get; set; }
        public int? NewPlant1 { get; set; }
        public string NewPlant1SubHeadline { get; set; }
        public int? NewPlant2 { get; set; }
        public string NewPlant2SubHeadline { get; set; }
        public int? NewPlant3 { get; set; }
        public string NewPlant3SubHeadline { get; set; }
        public string NewPlantMonth { get; set; }

        public virtual NewsletterComponents NewsletterComponents { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: the `newsletterNewPlants` is not tracked before and once set as a reference of the tracked entity `dbComponent`, it will become added. It seems to have an positive `Id` that matches with some `NewsletterNewPlants` that's already saved in your db. If you want to add a new `newsletterNewPlants`, make sure that its `Id` is non-positive. Otherwise (updating), you need to make a round for its updating logic, either load the current reference from db (so it's tracked) or manually set `Modified` state for the new instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I was missing a reference to newsletterNewPlants. I managed to solve it. Your answer definitely helped me figure out what is wrong with my code. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting only `NewsletterComponents` I modified the code to get a reference of `newsletterNewPlants` also.

I changed the following line

```
var dbComponent = _context.NewsletterComponents.Find(component.NewsletterComponentId);
```

to

```
var dbComponent = _context.NewsletterComponents.Include(t => t.NewsletterNewPlants).FirstOrDefault(t => t.NewsletterComponentId == component.NewsletterComponentId);
```